# finding associate terms : findAssocs not returning result

Tags: r, nlp

`findAssocs` returns <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) for all of my input and I'm not smart enough to figure out why. I've posted the code underneath to show you my steps, thanks in advance!

*read in files*

```
text <- readLines(list.files())
text <- readLines(file.choose())
text <- pdf_text(file.choose())
```

*collapse*

```
text <- paste(unlist(text), collapse ="")
```

*convert to corpus*

```
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))`
```

*clean*

```
toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("dutch"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
```

*dtm*

```
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
```

*associate terms*

```
as.data.frame(findAssocs(dtm, terms = "security", corlimit = 0.3))
```

**SUBSET:**

```
 [976] "how to utilize public or hybrid clouds without"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [977] "compromising the overall security posture and at"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 [978] "the same time leveraging cost and scaling benefits"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [979] "of the cloud."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [980] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 [981] "If we take a holistic view of the non-technical challenges, it boils down to how the mid-to-large sized"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [982] "IT departments are organized. The typical organization is divided into for example a network team,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [983] "a server team, a security team and an application"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [984] "team working perfectly within their respective silo"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [985] "but rarely frictionless between the silos."
```

Comment: Please provide an small text input reproducing the problem. Just a small subset of `text` vector is enough

Comment: BTW, in the first 3 lines where you read text, I hope you're just using one of them, because every time you're overwriting `text` vector

Comment: @digEmAll I've added a small sample of the text in the main question! Also, I make a choice (it be either txt or pdf file) so no worries haha.

Comment: Running your code with this subset works fine. If you look at object d do you have a lot of words in it? If so, try lowering the `corlimit`.

Comment: I've done as you suggested. It works now and you were right: a ton of words (3.2k). I failed to understand that. Thanks to both of you! phiver and
@digEmAll